# Promise.all in Async Method

Tags: javascript, axios

Having an issue that I can't workout with Promises. The below code was working when it was in server.js but I've split the code containing the network calls out into a class and now this one method is causing issues.

getItemDetails is behaving like a synchronous method, execution returns to the next line in server.js after the .then() is reached and I can't understand why that would be the case.

**Class:**

```
async getItemDetails(itemList) {

    let itemDetails = [];    
    Promise.all(itemList.map(id => this.axios.get(`/api/Item/${id.ItemID}/details`)))
        .then(responses => {
            responses.forEach(
                response => itemDetails.push(response.data)
            )
        })
        .then(() => {
            return itemDetails;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

**server.js**

```
(async () => {

    let itemList = await getItems() // Calls API to get a list of Items

    let detailList = await getItemDetails(itemList); // Retrieve details for hundreds of items


})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in an async function, so don't use `.then().catch()` with that Promise.all: `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar around Promises, and intended to take away the problem of then/then/then/catch/then/catch/etc/etc chaining. Instead you write code that's basically vanilla JS except for tactical `await` in front of promises/async calls:

```
async getItemDetails(itemList) {
  const items = await Promise.all(
    itemList.map(id =>
      this.axios.get(`/api/Item/${id.ItemID}/details`)
    )
  );

  return items.map(response => response.data);
}
```

Or, alternatively, if you really want to *explicitly* do everything in Promises, remove the `async` keyword because then you don't need it:

```
getItemDetails(itemList) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.all(
    itemList.map(id =>
      this.axios.get(`/api/Item/${id.ItemID}/details`)
    )
  )
  .then(responses => resolve(responses.map(r => r.data))
  .catch(err => reject(err));
}
```

And note that as far as callers can tell, those are *the same* functions, yielding *the same* result: an `async` function returns a Promise, and `await` is simply shorthand code for resolving a promise to a value.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: removed my code-sample, another answer has a much better implementation.

JavaScript processes synchronous code before asynchronous, promises need to be resolved. `async/await` allows to write less nested code, although it's worth keeping in mind: the promise still needs to resolve/reject.

Alternatively, use `async/await` and re-write it using a more synchronous style (using await for promises of course).

Otherwise, JavaScript will look at the method, see it has asynchronous work to do, complete the synchronous code and finish executing the `.then()`, of course, this is after the method has completed.